# Shopify app: adding a new shipping address via webhook

Tags: python, django, shopify

I'm planning to create a simple app using Django/Python that shows a nice button when installed by the store owner on user's account.

Clicking on that button should trigger a webhook request to our servers that would send back the generated shipping address for the user.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to create such button through shopify API or this something the store owner must manually add?
2. Is it possible to add a shipping address upon user request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the recipe:

- create a Proxy in your App to accept incoming Ajax call from customer
- create a form and button in customer liquid that submits to your Proxy
- in the App Proxy, validate the call from Shopify and when valid, look for your form params.
- open the customer record with the ID of the customer you sent along with the form data, and add an address to their account

Done. Simple.

Comment: Thanks for the guideline, I need to learn those parts to fully implement this, can you refer me to some good tutorials/docs to accomplish the items in your recipe?

Comment: There are hundreds, if not thousands of Python resources out there. I can't help you help yourself there. I think the Zed Shaw Learn Python the Easy Way is decent?

Comment: how do i create the button?
Can I do it automatically on app install?

Comment: in the Liquid you provide... render a button

Comment: Where do you suggest placing that button?
I couldn't find info on the customer liquid thin, it would be great if you can explain how it works

Comment: you create a form in HTML and submit to your App Proxy. I assume you know HTML, which has buttons etc.